# C# raise An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' from a F# library

Tags: c#, dll, exception, f#, missingmethodexception

I made c# project using GeckoFx and I'm calling a f# function in a dll I made.

The  c# code which calls the function is:

```
var myList = geckoWebBrowser1.ActiveNetworkChannelUrls;
hist.Add(geckoWebBrowser1.Url.ToString());
resCoo = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
myHTML = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
// gets the ISIN list from html table
var myISINSt = HTMLFuncs.GetISINStocks(myHTML);
```

and the exception is rised on the last row, and is:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   CSGeckoTest01.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Impossibile trovare il metodo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
>   FSharp.Data.HtmlNodeModule.descendants(Boolean,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2,
>   FSharp.Data.HtmlNode)'.

I'm sure the function is in the library (at least VS Object Browser can see it), I tested it in FSI and it works.

I found a similar problem in:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/22608519/fsharp-data-system-missingmethodexception-when-calling-freebase-provider-from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608519/fsharp-data-system-missingmethodexception-when-calling-freebase-provider-from)

and followed the solution, but it doesn't work for me.

Please, can someone help?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you share the F# function you are trying to call?

Comment: In my experience, `MissingMethodException` is always caused by a versioning, or other assembly identity, issue. You may have to troubleshoot how assemblies are loaded.

Comment: As @MarkSeemann says, this is probably assembly loading error - my guess is that the application loads an incompatible version of `FSharp.Core.dll`. Can you try adding binding redirect? Mark has a blog post about it: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/

Comment: Check that the FSharp.Core.dll in the project is the same version as the one used in the Test project.

Comment: Thank you to everybody. The problem was actually a different version of FSharp.Core.dll . Following your suggestions, I enabled automatic binding redirects manually in the project, and now it works!!!