# Why am I getting System.MissingMethodException when calling a custom library?

Tags: dll, f#, missingmethodexception

I have a library project called `MyLib`, in which I have a namespace called `Extensions`, in which there is a module called `Extension1`, which has a method called `ext1Method1` of type `string -> string`.

In the solution for the library project, there is an executable console project called `Test`.  Within `Test` I can call `MyLib.Extensions.Extension1.ext1Method1 str` and it works fine.

I have created a completely separate solution called `NewSol1` and included a reference to `MyLib.dll` in `NewSol1`.  In `NewSol1` there is a line

```
printfn "%s" (MyLib.Extensions.Extension1.ext1Method1 "Hello, World")
```

The solution `NewSol1` builds without any error.  But when I run the executable I get the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled

Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in NewSol1.exe

Additional information: Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<System.String> MyLib.Extensions.Extension1.ext1Method1(System.String)'.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34134858/636019

Comment: @ildjarn That solved the problem!  If you post the link as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting a succinct answer here even though the link provided by ildjarn answers the question: to fix the problem, ensure that the Nuget packages in the two solutions are the same.

In my case, the library used a slightly older version of `FSharp.Core`.  Since I had the freedom to recompile the library against any version of `FSharp.Core`, I chose to update all the Nuget packages in both the library and the consumer.  I did this by right-clicking the library solution, choosing `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution...` and making sure all of the packages were up-to-date.