# Using FSharp.Data in C# Script

Tags: f#-interactive, f#-data, c#-interactive

I've built an F# Library using the `FSharp.Data 2.3.1`.

When I use my library in a C# Console Project everything works, but in a C# Script file (.csx / C# Interactive) I get the following error:

`Method not found: Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync1<System.IO.TextReader> FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntimeWithDesignTimeRules(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)'.`

I have verified that:

- I'm using the same `FSharp.Data` and `FSharp.Core` dlls in the C# Script file. I have tried using the portable versions but the result is the same.
- My [F# Library isn't a PLC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22609725/1229323)

And finally, when I use my library in the F# interactive everything works.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you referencing the F# library in the C# script?

Comment: @PauloMorgado my r directives: `#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.3.1/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll" - #r "FSharp.Core.dll" - #r "Library1.dll"` I've verified the paths are ok

Comment: Are those the only assemblies your console application is referencing?